# Programmatic distinction between ternary then function call versus function call dependent on condition

Tags: python, function, ternary-operator

Recently I have been conflicted regarding the following question. It may just be a stylistic choice, but I was wondering if there is a programmatic difference between the following... (in python, but applicable for most languages)

Case #1:

```
arg = A if condition else B
result = func(arg)
```

Case #2:

```
if condition:
    result = func(A)
else:
    result = func(B)
```

Is there an industry standard for choosing between these two? Is there a programmatic difference?

Comment: Nope, just style. Obviously in the former it's easier to switch out the function being called, but outside of trivial examples just use whichever makes most sense in context.

Comment: I'd probably do `result = func(A if condition else B)`

Answer (score 0):

My opinion is in Case #1 you'd better be sure that you're checking for some kind of binary condition, e.g. an integer is either odd or even. In thoses cases I'd prefer Case #1 for the sake of simplicity.

If the expression in the condition is not binary, such as checking the remainder of an integer module n, with n > 2, you make need to use a nested ternary expression, and the code gets hard to read quickly. In theses cases, Case #2 would be better.